# JScript/CScript promise

Tags: javascript, jscript, q, wsh

I am currently trying to run Q promise library from JScript/CScript from command prompt. But it seems that JScript is throwing an error when it tries to execute/eval the code.

Code:

```
function createXMLHTTPObject() {
var XMLHttpFactories = [
    function () {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
];
var xmlhttp = false;
for (var i=0;i<XMLHttpFactories.length;i++) {
    try {
        xmlhttp = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
    }
    catch (e) {
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
   return xmlhttp;
}
var loadScript = function(url){
  var script= createXMLHTTPObject();
  script.Open("GET",url,false);
  script.Send()
  var response = eval(script.responseText);
}
//execute Q library
loadScript("http://jquery-for-admins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jq4a.js");
loadScript("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min.js");
loadScript("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.0.1/q.js");
```

This is the execution code from cmd:

```
wscript //x script.js
```

The code above could execute jquery4admin and json2.min.js. But for some reasons it couldn't execute the Q library. So the question is: Is there any other promise library that support JScript/CScript? If it is not possible then I will just run all XHR in synchronous mode.

Update:
the error was actually within q.js, when I tried to declare the deferred object and resolve it, visual studio debugger basically break and stopped at this line of code:
`// old browsers
        requestTick = function () {
            setTimeout(flush, 0);
        };`

And this is what visual studio says:

> Unhandled exception at line 618, column 13 in eval code
>
> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us the error it was throwing?

Comment: Maybe its wrong url? try

    `loadScript("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.0.1/q.js");`

Comment: @SimonPlus I have updated the url, and the error was actually within q.js, when I tried to declare the deferred object and resolve it, visual studio debugger basically break and stopped at this line of code: // old browsers         requestTick = function () {             setTimeout(flush, 0);         };

Comment: I had the same problem. After all, I figured out that Promise libraries usually use `setTimeout()` and it does not exist in JScript. Did you find a lib that doesn't use `setTimeout()` it and works with JScript?